# File 'Windows.props' not found

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have install Windows 8.1 and after that I install Visual Studio Express 2013, which includes Update 2 RC.So when I run any application then it gives me the error

```
"File 'Windows.props' not found"
```

I don't know why it is happening. I search a lot about this error but can't find any solution.Please help me I have spend two days to find this solution.

### Edit

Also there is not Emulator in the Device list.I think error is due to this once.I have download the 8.1 Emulator but cant find in the VS 2013 Emulator list.

Comment: Hi Azam..Check This discussion..http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/58daea5a-3abb-4952-9c17-36c1dfbc2aee/error-after-installing-visual-studio-2013?forum=toolsforwinapps

Comment: @loop I have already read the entire discussion but not able to solve this.

Comment: What about a reinstall ?

Comment: I have reinstall and also repair but facing same error.

Answer (score 8):

Some basic checks you need to perform to get anywhere close to a resolution.

The Windows.props file is a build file that's used by MSBuild.exe when it builds a Windows Phone app.  The normal install path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.props.  Use Windows Explorer to check if the file is present.

Then there is a line in the main .targets file that includes it.  It tries to locate the file in the `$(TargetPlatformWinMDLocation)` directory.  You can see the value of this macro by increasing the build verbosity.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  Change the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting to `Detailed`.  Use Build + Rebuild on your project.  Scroll back the Output window and locate the lines that resemble this:

```
1>TargetPlatformSdkMetadataLocation = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral
1>TargetPlatformSdkPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\
1>TargetPlatformSdkRootOverride = 
1>TargetPlatformVersion = 8.1
1>TargetPlatformWinMDLocation = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral
```

Tell us if you see anything different.

This path is read from the registry.  Startup Regedit.exe and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Install Path` as well as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\Install Path`.
Verify that you see a value listed in those keys with the name `"Install Path"` and that it contains the value `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\"`.

Comment: I follow all the steps that you mentioned.Firs of all I try to find that .props file in mentioned directory but unfortunately I did not find that file.Second in registry I just found the 8.0 version (folder) 8.1 was not mentioned there.

Comment: That's rather bad, you will have to troubleshoot the installation failure.  A starting point would be ensure that you have the correct Express edition.  You want the one "for Windows", not the one "for Desktop".  You'll have to dig through the install log files in your TEMP directory and look for errors.

Comment: I download the sdk included the VS Express edition.I don't figure it out why I am getting this error.
I am now using wp 8.0 for development and it's working perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Extracts from msdn discussion:

check for the existence of a SYSTEM level environment variable called windowsSDKDir and try removing it.

```
For this Follow these steps:

Press Windows Key + X and select System.
In the System dialog click on "Advanced system settings" then click "Environment Variables" on the advanced tab.
Then look for the environment variable I mentioned
try removing it
```

If this not works for you ,you must re-install, Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1 this must solve your problem.

Comment: that variable is not there.

Comment: [Have you checked this update](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-may-12-vs)

Comment: the latest version of SDK is included this update.So no need to update it again.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be bound to the VS2013 Update4. I had no issues before, but after this, I needed to Install the [Windows Software Development Kit for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) as Ludwo suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I used function 'Repair' in control panel -> programs and functions -> Windows Software Development Kit for Windows 8.1 ->Change and solved this problem.

Comment: Worked for me! Although I don't see C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.props as Hans described, but projects can be rebuilt and running well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to install [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) (Not Windows Phone SDK!) to fix it. I have VS2013 update 4

Answer (score 0):

have you checked for the existence of a SYSTEM level environment variable called windowsSDKDir? and try removing it?(make a note of its value first in case you need to re-instate it at some point). For some this appears to have been causing the error.  It is not clear at this stage what creates this.

Comment: not alinem that variable is not in SYSTEM level Environment