# Cordova and Windows 10 Target: "No sdk found" error when building

Tags: windows, cordova

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 Community.

I've installed cordova via npm following the instructions on the home of the project.

I've created a project.Then I've added window platform (to be able to build windows 10 universal app), but when I try to run it (no modifiation done yet) I got

> C:\Users\\TestApp>cordova build windows --appx=uap Running command: cmd "/s /c
>   "C:\Users\\TestApp\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat""
>
> MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\
>   Building project:
>   C:\Users\\TestApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj
>
> ```
>     Configuration : debug
>     Platform      : anycpu
> ```
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1966,5):
>   warning MSB3785: nessun SDK trovato.
>
> Gli elementi SDKReference non verranno risolti. Se l'applicazione
>   richiede tali riferimenti, è possibile  che si verifichino errori di
>   compilazione.
>   [C:\Users\\TestApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj]
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(633,5):
>   error APPX3213: la cartella SDK contenente 'Windows.props' per
>   'Windows 8.1' non è stata trovata.
>
> Per altre informazioni, vedere
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12560&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=Windows&o2=8.1. [C:\Users\\TestApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj]
>   ERROR: Error code 1 for command: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\msbuild with args:
>   C:\Users\\TestApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj,/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=debug,/p:Platform=anycpu
>   ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with
>   exit code 2

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

Sorry, the error text is in italian, but of course it's simply telling that Cordova can't find the SDK for build my project.

Because I actively use VS 2015, and can build C# projects without problems, I think all required (.NET ?) components are installed.

Can you help me to detect the problem?

Comment: It looks like the error is in trying to build Windows 8.1. Are you running Windows 10 or Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched and found a thread with a similar problem. [File 'Windows.props' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442152/file-windows-props-not-found)

It will probably be best to do a repair on your Visual Studio 2015, making sure that you have the most up to date Windows SDKs. The missing Windows.props file has to do with the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK. There's more detail about this in the linked thread.

Comment: Yes, the solution was simply this. I reinstalled VS 2015 adding some SDKs I kept out until now, because I was only developing on C# for desktop applications. Now I've 12 GB less of free disk space on my SSD. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

If u have another copy of this project then just copy this file ***CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj*** and paste in project/platform/windows. I was having same issue i solved it by doing this.